# Replace "/" in string with "${parameter/pattern/string}"?

Tags: bash

I have a parameter `$1` that for example is set to the string `operations/software/tools-manifest` and I want to transform that to the string `operations-software-tools-manifest`, i. e. replace all slashes (`/`) with dashes (`-`).  Is this possible with `bash` alone, not calling for example `sed(1)`?

I tried (unsucessfully):

```
[tim@passepartout ~]$ testparam=operations/software/tools-manifest
[tim@passepartout ~]$ echo "${testparam////-/}"
operations-/software-/tools-manifest
[tim@passepartout ~]$ echo "${testparam///-/}"
operations/software/tools-manifest
[tim@passepartout ~]$ echo "${testparam//\//-/}"
operations-/software-/tools-manifest
[tim@passepartout ~]$ echo "${testparam//\\//-/}"
operations/software/tools-manifest
[tim@passepartout ~]$ echo "${testparam//[/]/-/}"
operations/software/tools-manifest
[tim@passepartout ~]$ echo "${testparam//\x2f/-/}"
operations/software/tools-manifest
[tim@passepartout ~]$ echo "${testparam//\57/-/}"
operations/software/tools-manifest
[tim@passepartout ~]$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `"${testparam//\//-}"` to replace all the forward slashes by `-`:

```
echo "${testparam//\//-}"
operations-software-tools-manifest
```

Comment: *argl*  Why did I use a trailing `/` in my tests?!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One of the easiest, most general-purpose ways to do this is to put your source and destination in variables.

```
in="/"
out="-"
testparam=operations/software/tools-manifest
echo "${testparam//$in/$out}"
```

---

If you want to also suppress globbing (for this to work when `in='*'` and `testparam='hello*cruel*world'`), then you need to quote `"$in"`:

```
in="*"
out="-"
testparam='operations*software*tools'
echo "${testparam//"$in"/$out}"
```

Without the extra quotes, a single `*` will expand to match the entire input string, so the output will contain only `-`.